# How do i add 2 Big O notations

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have algorithm one that has a complexity of  O(mnr +mr^2 + nr^2 ) + K x (mr^2 + nr^2)

and the second algorithm  which is Estep = Q.*X + (1-Q).*(W*H) which i computed as O(mnr)

where (.) is element-wise multiplication

Now i want to add O(mnr) to O(mnr) +mr^2 + nr^2 + K x (mr^2 + nr^2)

Question:

1. do you agree with my complexity of the second statement?
2. what will be the final complexity

Thanks for your time

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something with sparse deep nonnegative matrix factorization. I deleted my answer because I'm not qualified to advise you on that, but I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify `O(mnr) + O(mnr +mr^2 + nr^2) + K x (mr^2 + nr^2)` as
`O(mnr + mr^2 + nr^2)`. You cannot simplify further without any assumption on the relationship between `m`, `n` and `r`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. first of all do u agree with the complexity of  Estep = Q.X + (1-Q).(W*H) being O(mnr)?